# calling c++ function from c

Tags: c++, c, linux

I need to access a C++ function from C but I get some error like :-

```
/tmp/ccUqcSZT.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `load_alert_to_db'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My main.c code is:-

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    extern void load_alert_to_db(void);     
    int main(void){
        /* Create empty queue */
        load_alert_to_db(); 
        return 0;
    }
```

C++ code implementation db_manager.cpp is:-

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

//using namespace oracle::occi;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void load_alert_to_db(void)
{
    cout<<"db occi"<<endl;
}
```

makefile is:-

```
CC= g++
all:    
    $(CC) -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC db_manager.cpp 
    $(CC) -shared -o libdb_manager.so db_manager.o
    gcc -L/home/oracle/Desktop/storage/ -Wall main.c -o data -ldb_manager
    gcc -o data main.c 

clean:
    rm -f *.o data
```

so please help me which one is my problem. I am also include

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Desktop/storage/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

environmental variable in `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -o data main.c
```

Not sure *why* you have this line in your makefile since it will compile `main.c` *without* reference to the previously created library and hence cause an undefined-symbol error such as the one you're seeing.

This is especially so, since you appear to have done it the *right* way on the preceding line:

```
gcc -L/home/oracle/Desktop/storage/ -Wall main.c -o data -ldb_manager
```

However, the entire point of using makefiles is so that it figures out the minimum necessary commands for you, based on dependencies. Lumping a large swathe of commands into a single rule tends to defeat that purpose. You would be better off making your rules a little more targeted, such as (untested but should be close):

```
all: data

data: main.o libdb_manager.so
    gcc -o data main.o -ldb_manager

main.o: main.c
    gcc -o main.o main.c

libdb_manager.so: db_manager.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o db_manager.o db_manager.cpp 
    g++ -shared -o libdb_manager.so db_manager.o
```

That way, if you make a small change to one part (like `main.c`), it doesn't have to go and compile/link everything in your build tree.

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile seems to be completely broken and random, and you're not even linking the required object files. You can simplify this:

```
all:    
    $(CC) -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC db_manager.cpp 
    $(CC) -shared -o libdb_manager.so db_manager.o
    gcc -L/home/oracle/Desktop/storage/ -Wall main.c -o data -ldb_manager
    gcc -o data main.c
```

to just this:

```
all:    
    gcc -Wall -c main.c 
    g++ -Wall -c db_manager.cpp
    g++ main.o db_manager.o -o data
```

Comment: Did you *want* to be passing C++ source to `gcc`? I don't think that works too well, since it will want `g++`.

Comment: @Paul R thanks for your response but the makefile which you suggest is not know the cpp library for example the error what i get is when i use your makefile db_manager.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'

Comment: @SisayZinabu: did you use `gcc` or `g++` in the makefile ?

Comment: @paxdiablo gcc will compile and link C++ just fine, it just doesn't automatically link the standard C++ library.

Comment: @Paul R i am using both my objective is to mix c and c++ to call function of c++ in c

Comment: @SisayZinabu: yes, that's fine - you can still use g++ for mixed .c and .cpp builds. I've updated the answer though to use separate compilation for the C and C++ source files now, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I needed to do:
Supposing the C++ function is called Debug::Write(str) 
Then in your hpp file do the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" void DebugTmp(char *str);
#endif
```

Then in the corresponding cpp file do this:

```
void DebugTmp(char *str)
{
    Debug::Write(str);
}
```

Then in your C file where you call DebugTmp define the prototype:

```
void DebugTmp(char *str);
```

then call it as below:

```
static void MyFunction( void )
{
    DebugTmp("This is debug trace\n");
}
```